# Large e in RSA but not Wiener attacks

Tags: rsa

How to find $d$ with large $e$ ? If $(3\cdot d)^4 \le n$ : Wiener attacks, so what if $(3\cdot d)^4 > n$ ?

Comment: Wiener's bound has been slightly improved, see the links at the beginning in this [old answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2557/555) I made to a [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2544/555). I've not reviewed the status of the problem in a long time. A classical result is Dan Boneh and Glenn Durfee's [Cryptanalysis of RSA with Private Key $d$ Less than $N^{0.292}$](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1).