# How is it possible to derive the public exponent from an RSA private key?

Tags: rsa, key-generation

I am gonna write down formulas that I know and use to generate RSA keys.

1. we choose $p$, $q$
2. $N = p\cdot q$
3. $\varphi(n) = (p-1)\cdot(q-1)$
4. choose $e$ such as

   - $1 < e < \varphi(N)$
   - $e$ is coprime with $N$, $\varphi(n)$
5. choose $d$  so that $d\cdot e\bmod\varphi(n)=1$

---

That's it. With these, if we have $p=2$ and $q=7$,  I successfully get $d=11$ and $e=5$ which is correct.

Now Imagine, that I only have private key which is $(11,14)$ (that is $d=11$, $N=14$). How do I get $e=5$. I understand that with $d$ and $N$, you can't directly get $e$, but as RSA works, it tries different variants of $e$ , then checks and if it's valid, that's how you get public key from private key.

Can anyone explain to me what steps should I take here to figure out what $e$ could be and then from those, which $e$ should I choose ?

Comment: Note: You forgot $p\ne q$, which is necessary if you define $\varphi(n) = (p-1)\cdot(q-1)$, or want encryption/decryption to always work. The requirement that $e$ is coprime with $N$ is unusual. The requirement that $1<e<\varphi(n)$ is also slightly unusual for RSA as practiced, it's more usual to have $1<e<N$ (PKCS#1) or $2^{16}<e<2^{256}$ (FIPS 186-4).

Comment: If you've got a signature you can just test your guess by verifying it. That wont work for ciphertext though, at least not if you use a randomized padding scheme. With textbook RSA that might still work. I'm not sure if you can calculate $e$ if you've got nothing to verify against and *if $e$ is chosen randomly*. It might be possible to do something if it is chosen deterministically given [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25907/1172): guess $e$, calculate $p$ and $q$, check if it matches the deterministic algorithm.

Comment: What formula do I use so that at least I can start gessing `e` if I have `d` and `N` ? In my above formulas, it still doesn't make sense how I write a program that guesses `e`..

Comment: In practice, the private key consists of (at least) $p,q,$ and $e$. $d$ and $N$ can easily be computed from these, and are often stored along with $p,q,$ and $e$; but they are not essential. If all you have is $d$ and $N$, then you can't compute $e$ without factorising $N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's asked how, in RSA, one finds $e$ given $d$ and $N$. I'll ignore the question's requirement that $e$ is coprime with $N$, which is highly unusual and has no mathematical relevance. I'll also assume $p\ne q$, because it's necessary for the stated $\varphi(N)=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)$ to hold.

With the question's definition of RSA, the method to find $e$ goes

- Factor $N$ to find $p$ and $q$
- Compute $\varphi=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)$
- Compute $e$ knowing $e\cdot d\bmod\varphi=1$ and $1<e<\varphi$. That $e$ is uniquely defined, and the modular inverse of $d$ in the [multiplicative group of integer modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) $\varphi$. For small numbers, a working method is trial and error of small odd $e>1$. A more constructive method is the (half)-[extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures), which computes $e=d^{-1}\bmod \varphi$ directly. For a practical algorithm that uses only non-negative integers:

  1. $a\gets d\bmod \varphi$ , $b\gets \varphi$ , $x\gets0$ and $y\gets1$
     Note: $a\cdot x+b\cdot y=\varphi$ will keep holding
  2. if $a=1$, then output *"the desired inverse $e$ of $d$ modulo $\varphi$ is $y$"* and stop
  3. If $a=0$, then output *"the desired inverse $e$ of $d$ modulo $\varphi$ does not exist"* and stop
  4. $r\gets\lfloor b/a\rfloor$
  5. $b\gets b-a\cdot r$ and $x\gets x+r\cdot y$
  6. if $b=1$, then output *"the desired inverse $e$ of $d$ modulo $\varphi$ is $\varphi-x$"* and stop
  7. If $b=0$, then output *"the desired inverse $e$ of $d$ modulo $\varphi$ does not exist"* and stop
  8. $r\gets\lfloor a/b\rfloor$
  9. $a\gets a-b\cdot r$ and $y\gets y+r\cdot x$
  10. Continue at 2

This same method is typically used to compute $d$ from $e$, since $d$ and $e$ are symmetric in $e\cdot d\bmod\varphi=1$. That's however not how $d=11$ was computed in the question; for some strange reason the question requires $e<\varphi(N)$ but not $d<\varphi(N)$, or the more usual $d<N$ or $d<\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

---

Serious problem with this approach for RSA as practiced (thus very large $N$, at least hundreds decimal digits): It won't work, because $N$ will be so large that it can't be factored, thus $\varphi$ can't be computed in this way.

Also, the question's condition $e\cdot d\bmod\varphi(N)=1$ is a sufficient, but not a necessary condition for textbook RSA encryption using $(e,N)$ to be undone by RSA decryption using $(d,N)$, and vice versa. The necessary condition is $e\cdot d\bmod\lambda(N)=1$, where $\lambda(N)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$. That condition is often used in practice: it's allowed by [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=7), and mandated by [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=60). Artificially small example: $N=341$, $e=7$, $d=13$ works just fine for textbook RSA encryption/decryption, yet $e\cdot d\bmod\varphi(N)=1$ does not hold (in this example $p=11$, $q=31$, $\varphi(N)=300$, $\lambda(N)=30$ ).

However, in RSA as practiced, $e$ is small, often small enough that $e$ can be found by enumeration. Thus a method could be:

- compute $c\gets2^d\bmod N$
- compute $c_2\gets c^2\bmod N$
- set $e\gets1$
- repeat

  - set $e\gets e+2$
  - set $c\gets c\cdot c_2\bmod N$; notice $c=2^{d\cdot e}\bmod N$
  - if $c=2$

    - for $m$ the first hundred odd primes (note: for small $N$, we want to stop as soon as $m^2>N$ )

      - if $m^{e\cdot d}\bmod N\ne m$, continue at *repeat* above
    - output $e$ and stop.

It's almost certain that if an $e$ is output, it's valid in the sense that textbook RSA encryption using $(e,N)$ is undone by RSA decryption using $(d,N)$, and (equivalently) $e\cdot d\bmod\lambda(N)=1$. It's not quite sure $e\cdot d\bmod\varphi(N)=1$, but knowing $e\cdot d$ and $N$ it's possible to factor $N$ (using [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62487/555) algorithm), and then compute *the* $e$ with $e\cdot d\bmod\varphi(N)=1$ and $1<e<\varphi(N)$, if for some reason that's desired.

---

Addition: The above is far from optimal. When $\delta=\ln(e)/\ln(N)$ is below a certain threshold, in the order of $0.292$, there are ways to factor $N$ (and thus solve the problem by the first method discussed). Basically, we swap $d$ and $e$ in Dan Boneh and Glenn Durfee's [Cryptanalysis of RSA with Private Key $d$ Less than $N^{0.292}$](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48910-X_1.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1). See [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2544/555) for more.

Comment: Of course, $p-1$ and $q-1$ should *not* have any *big* factor in common, or else your method of generating primes sucks and makes attacks undesiredly feasible (in fact, a lort more simple relations between $p,q$ must be avoided)). So preferably, $\lambda(p-1,q-1)$ is something like $\frac12\phi(N)$.  - Moreover, in practice one often picks a nice (public) $e$ such as a smallish, but not too small prime near a power of $2$; this makes computing the encryption faster while at the same time it is not much of a problem to avoid primes $\equiv 1\pmod e$ in the very process of generating them